# watching for variable changes during unitt esting

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-unit-test

I am working on a component that mainly does its job on onNgInit() method:

```
      stage = '';
      onNgInit(){
      const thus : any = this;
      this.stage = "start';
      this.uniService.dataExists().then(result=>{
       // the data exists. get ProductTypes
       that.stockService.productTypes().subscribe(proTypes=>{

        vm.stage = "Setting status to products";
        proTypes.map(product....);
      });
     });
    }
```

now in my test, the value of stage remains "start" since the code is onNgInit, I believe. I was wondering if there is a way to watch for value change of variables or better yet, the very final value of a specific variable?

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { TrackerComponent } from "./tracker.component";

describe("TrackerComponent", () => {
  let component: TrackerComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TrackerComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [TrackerComponent]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TrackerComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
  //
  it("should is created", () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    expect(component.stage).toEqual('start');// want to track the changes

  });

});
```

Comment: you will have to call the `component.onNgInit` before assertion.

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to do/ what the problem is. Could you maybe rephrase the post?

Comment: @user3875919: `fixture.detectChanges` triggers a change detection cycle for the component and implicitly invokes its `ngOnInit` method, there's no need to explicitly invoke it again.

Comment: i thought this was not `ngOnInit` but `onNgInit`

Answer (score 0):

You need to synchronize the asynchronous calls to `uniService.dataExists().then` and `stockService.productTypes().subscribe` prior to check conditions with `exec`. This can be done using `fakeAsync` and `flush` in the second `beforeEach` function.

```
import { fakeAsync, flush } from '@angular/core/testing';
...
beforeEach(fakeAsync(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TrackerComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    flush();
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why you called it onNgInit when its ngOnInit but here is an answer assuming its a type:

You need to rewrite a little bit of your ngOnInit to return some sort of value.

```
  public async ngOnInit(): Promise<void>{
      const thus : any = this;
      this.stage = "start';
      const result = await this.uniService.dataExists();
       // the data exists. get ProductTypes
      const proTypes = await (that.stockService.productTypes().toPromise());
      this.stage = "Setting status to products";
      proTypes.map(product....);
  }
```

So in your UT you might have something like this:

```
 it("should is created", (done) => {
    expect(component.stage).toEqual('start');
    component.ngOnInit().then(() =>{
        expect(component.stage).toEqual('Setting status to products');          
        done();
    });
  });
```

Either this or switch from promises to observables.

Also you shouldn't just trust that functions sort of execute. When testing you should test each stop and its progression.